# Multisite installation on IIS gives 404 trying to access the admin dashboard

Tags: multisite, rewrite-rules, 404-error, iis

There appears to be a bug on the `web.config` file generated by WordPress, up to version 4.7.2, where the rewrite rules do not work as needed to access the sites defined in the network.

When using, for instance, sub-dir for the multisites configuration, trying to access `mysite.com/subsite/wp-admin/` gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this issue on the WordPress trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24963), the problem are the rules 4 and 5.

The solution is to change the url parameter and add 1, so, instead of this:

```
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

You have this:

```
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:3}" />
            </rule>
```

Doing this change allows the multisite feature to work.